# Underscore template - how to check multiple conditions

Tags: templates, underscore.js-templating

In my app, I am trying to check 2 conditions with the `if` part. But not working. I am not getting the result too..

here is my condition what i use :

```
<% _.each(recourseParameter, function (item, index) { %>

            <% if (index % limit == 0 )  { %>
                <%= _.template($('#header').html())({"parameterCode":parameterCode}) %>
            <% } %>

            <% if(item.description) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>

            <% if (((index+1) % limit == 0 ) && ((index +1) != limit)) { %> // this is not working!
                    <%= _.template($('#closer').html())() %>
                        <span>Continue ... </span> //this is not printing..
                    </div>
            <% }  %>

    <% }) %>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/3/)

Comment: Do you mind to check what is the error in your console log? I got this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6257603/recourseParameter.json
ERROR: error, but it could be the network here unable to connect to dropbox. I would try again at home. Is it ok in your side?

Comment: this is working fine for me. may be this url banned for you. In case you wish let me give you the static data based example?

Comment: @Hatjhie - here is the data placed within the fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if actually is working fine. The logic that the if code is trying to validate is incorrect.

Let's have a look.

```
<% if (((index+1) % limit == 0 ) && ((index +1) != limit))
```

> The possible value of index is 0 to 10  while the limit is always 9

Now to satisfy this requirement `(index+1) % limit == 0` 
the index must be 8, other than that the % won't be 0 since only `(8+1) % 9 == 0.`

Now, the index is 8. 
The second condition in if is `(index+1) != limit` which (8+1) != 9 that would always return false.

Thus, the  `<% if (((index+1) % limit == 0 ) && ((index +1) != limit))` would never return true.

In summary, the if function is working perfectly, please modify the logic of the codes accordingly:

Comment: Do you have any idea to modify this logic. since the template is very new to me.. I coun't get a best idea after some of try..

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. What is the original intention of creating that third if?

Comment: I am spliting the data in a group, which i define there is `limit`. when `limit` is 3 then i need to print group by 3 and need to say `continue`.  when the loop reach the last group, the continue became All are done.

User may define the `limit` as per their requirements. that's what i am trying to print with conditions.

Comment: you mean every third loop, you wanna display continue?

Comment: yes. and the last loop need to show `done' or complete.